# Matching parsed expressions in R

Tags: r, expression

Given a list of objects that are either symbols or language, what is the best way to search for containment?

For example, consider the following example:

```
> a = list(substitute(1 + 2), substitute(2 + 3))
> substitute(1 + 2) %in% a
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments
> a == substitute(1 + 2)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
Warning message:
In a == substitute(1 + 2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The second method seems to work, but I am unsure of what the warning means.

Another idea is to use `deparse` and then compare characters, but this becomes complicated when the parsed expressions are long enough to exceed the `width.cutoff` in `deparse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sue why you would need to do this but you can use `identical` to do the comparison. However, since `identical` only compares two arguments, you will have to loop over your list, preferably using `lapply`...

```
lapply( a , function(x) identical( substitute(1 + 2) , x ) )
#[[1]]
#[1] TRUE

#[[2]]
#[1] FALSE
```

Or similarly you can still use `==`. Inspection of `substitute(1 + 2)` reveals it to be a `language` object of length 3, whilst your list `a` is obviously of length 2, hence the warning on vector recycling. Therefore you just need to loop over the elements in your list which you can do thus:

```
lapply( a , `==` , substitute(1 + 2) )
#[[1]]
#[1] TRUE

#[[2]]
#[1] FALSE
```